# getting error on mysql #1089

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a following query that i have mention below, but it got me an error:

> getting error on mysql #1089

```
CREATE TABLE `fabrica`.`products` 
     ( 
                  `product_id`    INT NOT NULL auto_increment , 
                  `product_cat`   INT(100) NOT NULL , 
                  `product_title` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL , 
                  `product-price` INT(100) NOT NULL , 
                  `product_descp` TEXT NOT NULL , 
                  `product_img` TEXT NOT NULL , 
                  `product_keywords` TEXT NOT NULL , 
                  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`(100)) 
     ) 
     engine = innodb;
```

Comment: **What's the error?** Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines: [what kinds of questions can I ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [Minimal, complete, verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Then, `edit` your question with additional details so that we may help.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE fabrica.products ( 
    product_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
    product_cat INT(100) NOT NULL , 
    product_title VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL , 
    product-price INT(100) NOT NULL , 
    product_descp TEXT NOT NULL , 
    product_img TEXT NOT NULL , 
    product_keywords TEXT NOT NULL , 
    PRIMARY KEY (product_id(100))
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Remove 100 from primary key declaration you should just use the column name.

Change to:

```
CREATE TABLE fabrica.products ( 
    product_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
    product_cat INT(100) NOT NULL , 
    product_title VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL , 
    product_price INT(100) NOT NULL , 
    product_descp TEXT NOT NULL , 
    product_img TEXT NOT NULL , 
    product_keywords TEXT NOT NULL , 
    PRIMARY KEY (product_id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: ` INT(100) ` is not good idea too. use just ` INT`

Comment: The length for `INT` doesn't have any meaning without `ZEROFILL`. So `INT(100)`, `INT(10)`, `INT(1)` and `INT` are all the same in MySQL.